# Are there any ways to sum all the list values that are from dictionary?

Tags: python, typeerror

I was trying to make the program which will sum up all the prices that I chose. Here is the code:

```
Menu_list = {"Cola" : 500,
             "Cheese" : 400,
             "Burger" : 1000,
             "Sprite" : 500,
             "Ice Cream" : 300}

Order_list = []

print(Menu_list)
while True:
    a = input()
    Order_list.append(Menu_list.get(a))
    print(sum(Order_list))
```

1. I want to make while loop to be executed whenever I type the Menus that are in Menu_list. If not I want to get out of the while loop and return sum of the Order_list. So I tried "while a not in Menu_list", but it won't work.
2. I want to get the specific values from dictionary to list and sum all the list values. But it will show "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'".

Any solutions for these 2 problems?

Comment: Do you want to choose all the choices in one input? For example "Cheese, Cola, Burger". Or seperatly? First "Cheese" then "Cola" and then "Burger"?

Comment: Want to choose all the choices in one input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that will do the trick:

```
Menu_list = {"Cola" : 500,
             "Cheese" : 400,
             "Burger" : 1000,
             "Sprite" : 500,
             "Ice Cream" : 300}

Order_list = []

print(Menu_list)

a = "Start"

while a != "End":
    a = input()
    if a in Menu_list:
        Order_list.append(Menu_list[a])

    print("Sum of the list: {}".format(sum(Order_list)))
```

1. You need to end the While loop sometimes. This is achieved by checking the input - fi its `"End"` then we end the loop.
2. Also you need to check if the input is valid with this statement `if a in Menu_list:`

Comment: Thanks for your help ! one more question. Order_list.append(Menu_list(a)). if i use (a) it won't work. why so?

Comment: It is a `dictionary` not a `function`. You have to use `["key"]` to access the `Value`.

Comment: Also if the answer was useful please vote it up so others can see that it is valid :)

Comment: I voted . But "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." this pops up

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem: you need to set the variable "a" to an initial value that is in your dictionary. Otherwise the while loop doesn't execute at all. For example:

```
a = "Cola"
while a not in Menu_list:
...
```

For the second problem, make sure that your code doesn't add a price to the order list if a is not in the menu list, because then you have None in your order list. Like this:

```
if a in Menu_list:
    Order_list.append(Menu_list.get(a))
```